# Does GWT FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandle take into account the service set by FormPanel.setAction?

Tags: java, gwt

In `GWT`, I am uploading files using `FormPanel` with `FileUpload`.

I am associating a `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` as the action of the form (its purpose is to save the file to the server, making use of `Apache Commons FileUpload`

My question is this: I want to display an "Upload Success" message, so if I use a `SubmitCompleteHandler`; will the "completion" part of this process look at the outcome of the `servlet` - i.e. if the code in the `doPost`method executes correctly, or throws an exception? Or will its scope merely be to the end of the `POST` request containing the file?

Answer (score 0):

After coming to my senses, I debugged the relevant code and can confirm that the `SubmitCompleteHandler` doesn't 'fire' until the `FormPanel` action (in this case my servlet) has finished executing.